# How to start a function in chrome console when a text element in the html code appear?

Tags: javascript, html, full-text-search, countdowntimer

I've tried to write a script that fire a click on a specific element of an online website (not my website) and at a specific time. The specific time is given by a countdown that run inside the website.

by reading the html file of that website, the code (captured at a generic time) is like that:

```
<div class="thecountdowndown" id="counting"><div class="col-xs-3 col-sm-3 col-md-3 col-lg-3"><div>00</div><small>days</small></div><div class="col-xs-3 col-sm-3 col-md-3 col-lg-3"><div>23</div><small>hours</small></div><div class="col-xs-3 col-sm-3 col-md-3 col-lg-3"><div>12</div><small>minutes</small></div><div class="col-xs-3 col-sm-3 col-md-3 col-lg-3"><div>41</div><small>seconds</small></div></div>
```

[image of the code of the counter](https://i.stack.imgur.com/G6P7g.jpg).
So it's basically shown a timer, and every second the html code change.

My problem is that i can't figure it out how to write a functions that check when the code up here appear in the html!
This one is not working:

```
function searchTree(element, matchingTitle){
     if(element.title == matchingTitle){
          return element;
     }else if (element.children != null){
          var i;
          var result = null;
          for(i=0; result == null && i < element.children.length; i++){
               result = searchTree(element.children[i], matchingTitle);
          }
          return result;
     }
     return null;
}
```

I may should use var and a "While" loop: while the var has value 0, the function continues to search. but i don't know how to write the "searching" function.

And to say it all, i can't think about a way to start the "click" function after that the "searching" function has detected that the code is appeared.

Can anyone help me?

Update: in other words, there is a countdown on that website that start at midnight. Now, how i can (by using the chrome console) click a button when the countdown show the time "05:45:00"?  The button that i want to press is in the same page of the countdown.

Comment: are you trying to update the html as the counter ticks?

Comment: Nono I can't update the html because the site is an online site and is not my site. I'm trying to understand how to write a function that say to me if a specific code is inside the html or not. And if is not, that function will check over and over, until it appear.

Comment: There is no `title` in the html example you've give. In your code you're checking for it. If you already know the id/class of the element you can just use `document.querySelector`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```js
// just for simulating change in counter on HTML - already on website / dont inject through dev-tools
var seconds = 45;
setInterval(() => {
  document.getElementById("fakeChange").innerHTML = seconds--;
}, 1000);

// is injected through dev-tools / console by yourself
var elIdToObserve = 'counting';
var elIdToSimulateClick = 'submit';
// get the following value by manually calling: 
// console.log(document.getElementById(elIdToObserve).innerHTML)
var waitForContentAppearing = `
<div class="col-xs-3 col-sm-3 col-md-3 col-lg-3"><div>00</div><small>days</small></div>
<div class="col-xs-3 col-sm-3 col-md-3 col-lg-3"><div>23</div><small>hours</small></div>
<div class="col-xs-3 col-sm-3 col-md-3 col-lg-3"><div>12</div><small>minutes</small></div>
<div class="col-xs-3 col-sm-3 col-md-3 col-lg-3"><div id="fakeChange">41</div><small>seconds</small></div>
`; // change this to your target content i.e. seconds 46 to 41

setInterval(() => {
  if(document.getElementById(elIdToObserve).innerHTML === waitForContentAppearing) {
    // Add you own instructions here that should be executed

    // Since you mentioned there is a button within the webpage I added a button with id that gets a automated click - the button I added does do something i.e. for visualization I made the button show some text indicating it has been "clicked".
    document.getElementById(elIdToSimulateClick).click();
  }
}, 500);
```

```html
<!-- comes from existing website -->
<div class="thecountdowndown" id="counting">
<div class="col-xs-3 col-sm-3 col-md-3 col-lg-3"><div>00</div><small>days</small></div>
<div class="col-xs-3 col-sm-3 col-md-3 col-lg-3"><div>23</div><small>hours</small></div>
<div class="col-xs-3 col-sm-3 col-md-3 col-lg-3"><div>12</div><small>minutes</small></div>
<div class="col-xs-3 col-sm-3 col-md-3 col-lg-3"><div id="fakeChange">46</div><small>seconds</small></div>
</div>
<button id="submit" onclick="document.getElementById('simulationClick').innerHTML = 'Simulated click at timestamp '+Date.now()">Send</button>
<div id="simulationClick">
</div>
```

You might as well need to select via classes to get the Button you want to click on.

Comment: I can see the logic behind that, and is awesome and the code is very clear. I've tried to, but when i put in the Console, it return to me just a number, and no click event. why a number appear as a output?

Is the problem related to the fact that the counter on the website is located inside other div element? i've updated the code in the first post to better show the position of the counter.

Comment: I added a comment within the 500ms-Interval-Callback. What I understood is: There is a timer. The timer will reach a specific time (unique content by innerHTML). When the specific time is reached you want to trigger a button that is already on the page (in my example accessable through ID 'submit'). The button then does whatever it is programmed to do (in my example it does paste some text in somewhere/div to visualize the button has been clicked). Did I understood you right? Can you provide the page the timer is on, then I can adjust bit more?

Comment: yes you perfectly understood me. i've replaced the "submit" in the var elIdToSimulateClick = 'submit', with the id of the button of my interest. I don't know how much of the html i have to put in the  waitForContentAppearing = '  ', and i am not sure if i must replace the "counting" in elIdToObserve = 'counting' with a id that come earlier than "counting".

Comment: 1. step: `console.log(document.getElementById('counting').innerHTML)` will give you a snapshot of the content right now showing (i.e. `<p>my count 20:45:24</p>`) 2. step: change the snapshot of content from 1. step to your ideal target (i.e. `<p>my count 12:00:00</p>`) 3. step: insert the adapted / changed snapshot with your ideal target into `waitForContentAppearing=\`<p>my count 12:00:00</p>\`` 4. step: inject the whole script through dev-tools into the website in question and wait till the ideal target is reached.

Comment: It works!! i was defining in a wrong way the "waitForContentAppearing" ! Thank you David!

Answer (score 0):

You may have to tweak this a little bit, but it may help.

```js
const clickNow = function(targetElement, elementToClick) {

//May have to play with the selector to get node that holds the value
const timer = document.querySelector(targetElement);
setInterval(()=>{

    if(timer.value === "5:40:01 pm") {
        clickButton(elementToClick);
    }else {
        console.log("no yet", timer.value,"5:40:01 pm");
    }

},100)


    function clickButton(elementToClick) {
        const toClick = document.querySelector(elementToClick);
        toClick.click();
    }
}

clickNow("input[name='display2']",".t");
```